# Guide on Upgrading Spring Boot Starter Parent Version from 2.2.7.RELEASE to 2.7.17

Tags: spring-boot-starter-parent

I directly updated the Spring Boot Starter Parent version in my project from 2.2.7.RELEASE to 2.7.17 However, after making this change, I encountered several issues. Are there any breaking changes or deprecations that I should be aware of when migrating from Spring Boot 2.2.7.RELEASE to 2.7.17?

I undertook the following steps in an attempt to resolve the issues:

1. [updated the parent version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ufVT.png)
2. Ran mvn clean install
3. [Encountered problems while processing the POM, as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfsIh.png)
4. Fixed the error by adding the specific missing version of joda-time:joda-time,[as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGwbQ.png)
5. Ran mvn clean install again.
6. Encountered a new issue:
   cannot find symbol
   [ERROR]   symbol:   class Assert
   [ERROR]   location: package org.junit
7. To address the previous issue I added the junit 4 dependency along with junit5, As I'm using Junit5 but still by adding junit 4 dependency resolved my previous issue [junit4 dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeXvq.png)
8. Ran mvn clean install once more
9. Faced numerous test case failures:[depicted here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/913tW.png)

Despite attempting to rectify the test cases one by one, new issues continue to arise.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask].